# Rails Runner hanging with specific job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http

I have a Rails project and I am trying to run a script using Rails runner. This script runs fine on my local machine, but I am trying to run it on a new EC2 instance that I just set up.

When I run the script, it exhibits some very odd behavior. The first line in the script is a debug statement "Starting". When I say "hang" I mean that "Starting" is never printed.

```
rails runner Script.run //hangs forever
```

It is worth mentioning that the purpose of this script is to make several HTTP requests. So, in debugging it, I commented out various lines until I had the maximal program that would actually run.

The only line I needed to comment out is the one that actually called Net::HTTP.request. Then, the script would run, and print all of the debug statements that it was supposed to, but it wouldn't actually function as intended (obviously).

What seems odd to me is that the script will not even print "Starting" when the line that makes the HTTP request is present. The error would make some sense if it got to the HTTP request itself and then hung forever, or at least got some part of the way into the program.

What can cause Rails to behave this way? Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I actually made a dumb mistake, but I am going to answer my question for anyone who makes the same mistake in the future.

I forgot to add "$stdout.sync = true" to the config file, so Rails just appeared to be hanging because it was not writing to stdout. When the HTTP request was disabled, it ran fast enough so that I didn't notice the writing was delayed.